# Etymology of million vs. millennium

Tags: etymology, numbers

Why is it that a period of one thousand years is a millennium, but one million is a thousand thousands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The words *million* and *millennium* are formed differently and so mean different things.

*Millennium* is a Latinate compound of *mill-* meaning "thousand" and *-ennium*, meaning "year". (Compare related compounds such as *biennium* or *centennial*). Its meaning follows straightforwardly from its composition.

*Million*, on the other hand, [comes from a French or Italian word *million(e)*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=million) meaning "great thousand", which very early on came to mean "a thousand thousands". While this ultimately also goes back to the Latin root *mill-* for "thousand", the derivation is different, and so is the derived meaning.